# Adding Children in Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In the cocos2d engine, there is a method to add an object as a child of another.

So for example in this line of code in a Game.m file:

`CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:pauseButton, nil];
    pauseButton.position = ccp(s.width/2 - pauseButton.contentSize.width/2, (-s.height/2) 
                               + pauseButton.contentSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:menu z:100];`

You can see the menu instance of CCMenu is added as a child to the class object of Game. What does this actually do? Is it for memory purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of hierarchy system helps organize and reference your game components. And display them.

`Game.m` is your scene, and it will be displaying your game elements. However, it has no idea what those elements are. So the scene has a list of children, and it will "display" them (sprites, buttons, labels, etc...). So you add a child to the scene as a way to tell the scene that this child needs to be displayed, because it is a visual element.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa and Qt use this kind of hierarchy as well, where you can add one view as a child to another view. It has nothing to do with memory usage, it's main purpose is to have a clear order of responsibility (in Cocoa: responder chain).

In User Interfaces, the lowermost views get the first chance to react to user input. If a view doesn't react to user input it will pass on responsibility to its parent. In Cocos2D this isn't used however and it becomes mainly a system to position nodes relative to each other and to group nodes together so that they're all drawn on the same "depth layer".

The disadvantage of a tree-like hierarchy like this is that you can not easily iterate over all nodes in a scene without recursing into every child tree.